# nohup command could not generate the nohup.out file by rundeck job

Tags: nohup, rundeck

My rundeck job execute a simple nohup command "cd /tmp/; nohup ls -l &". the job execution log will get the command output but not generate the nohup.out file in that directory.

i used all kind of steps in rundeck workflow. all couldnot generate the nohup.out file.

Do anyone have any idea why rundeck couldnot generate the nohup.out file but send the command output to the execution logs?? thank

Answer (score 0):

You didn't seem to redirect the output to a file, nohup works fine in RunDeck from my experience.

```
cd /tmp/; nohup ls -l > /tmp/nohup.something
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working theory: `nohup` is being consumed/interpreted by the Rundeck infrastructure and interpreted approximately as: 'run this job indefinitely in the background' without our usual understanding of 'with output to a non-tty' (i.e. both stdout/stderr to nohup.out or piped together to file).  Or at least, I am fairly certain it is not executing the version of nohup that is on my path.

Thus:

1. you should manually redirect all of the output (stdout and stderr) to file unless you are content to let Rundeck capture it
2. you do not need the `&`, although it does not hurt anything

In my case, I translated from:

```
cd tools/celery && nohup ./start.sh flower > log_name.txt &
```

to:

```
cd tools/celery && nohup ./start.sh flower > log_name.txt 2>&1
```